# how to know software/tool is in which package in opensuse 13.1

Tags: package, opensuse, zypper

for example ,I want to compile opencv with gstreamer support, and it say

```
Package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found.
```

I have tried

```
sudo zypper in gstreamer-app-0.10
```

but I get:

```
Package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found.
```

finally I solved this by

```
sudo zypper in gstreamer-0_10-plugins-base-devel
```

so how do I know the "gstreamer-0_10-plugins-base-devel" provide the "gstreamer-app-0.10" ?
is there a command or way to search which package provides what library?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`zypper search --provides gstreamer-app-0.10`